# C# SQL Server Compact Insert solution

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to insert data into a SQL Server CE local database but having an issue I can't solve for the life of me.

```
foreach (var player in cells)
{
    var sql = new SqlCeConnection(
        @"Data Source=H:\Repositories\NHL-Connected\NHLConnected\NHLScraper\app.sdf");

    try
    {
        sql.Open();
        var cmd =
            new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Players (PlayerID, PlayerName, Team_Abbreviation) Values ( '" +
                player.ID.Replace("/ice/player.htm?id=", null) + "," + player.Name + "," +
                player.Team + "')", sql);

        int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (affectedRows > 0) Console.WriteLine("Successful.");
        else Console.WriteLine("Failed.");
    }
    catch (SqlCeException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The exception/error I'm getting is

> The count of column names and source expressions do not match [Column
>   name count = 3, Source expression count = 1]

I'm unsure if I'm doing this correctly.

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply misplaced and forgot some single quotes which results in a single string value. Maybe you should rethink how you construct your sql code and use parameters instead:

Try something like this:

```
var cmd = new SqlCeCommand(
    "INSERT INTO Players (PlayerID, PlayerName, Team_Abbreviation) VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Team);", sql);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", player.ID.Replace("/ice/player.htm?id=", null));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", player.Name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team", player.Team);
```

Comment: You should *definitely* use this!

Comment: I was just about to say I saw my mistake. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

You doing all in one " '  ' " <-- It thinks its one Column

```
try
{
var cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Players (PlayerID, PlayerName,  Team_Abbreviation) Values (@PlayerID,@PlayerName,@Team_Abbreviation)", sql);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerID", PlayerIDTxt);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerName", PlayerNameTxt);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team_Abbreviation", Team_AbbreviationTxt);

cmd.Open();
int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Close();

}

catch
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting single Quote as an extra character as below:

```
 new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Players (PlayerID, PlayerName, Team_Abbreviation) Values ( '" +
                                         player.ID.Replace("/ice/player.htm?id=", null) + "," + player.Name + "," +
                                         player.Team + "')", sql);
```

should be :

```
 new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Players (PlayerID, PlayerName, Team_Abbreviation) Values(player.ID.Replace("/ice/player.htm?id=", null) + ",'" + player.Name + "','" +
                                         player.Team + "')", sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a '`' to your variables, so they are 3 distinct ones

```
player.ID.Replace("/ice/player.htm?id=", null) + "," + player.Name + "," +
            player.Team + "')", sql);
```

in your code above, you have 1 ` to start, and one to end, you need one for each variable